# Chat application in Grails

Tags: grails, chat

I am trying to create a chat application in grails. I have no idea on doing this, so can you please point me in the correct direction. The application need not to be fancy, I just want a simple application.
Thanks

Comment: how many users? What kind of client? HTML?

Comment: not many users, most minimal type would do

Answer (score 0):

There is a blog that outlines the basic principles of this:

http://programmingitch.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/groovy-sockets-example.html

```
 import java.net.ServerSocket
 def server = new ServerSocket(4444)

 while(true) {
    server.accept { socket ->
       println "processing new connection..."
        socket.withStreams { input, output ->
            def reader = input.newReader()
            def buffer = reader.readLine()
            println "server received: $buffer"
            now = new Date()
           output << "echo-response($now): " + buffer + "\n"
    }
    println "processing/thread complete."
  }
}
```

This gives you the basic socket connections and input/output streams for a connected client.  You would have to adjust this to keep track of multiple clients and broadcast (send to all connected users) any messages from the server.